# Bookmark Elements of Table, Table Cell, Table Row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I want to achieve a bookmarking behavior like the example below using a custom script.

**Selecting all table cells from the table:**

[image]
[image]

**Select a table cell:**

[image]
[image]

**Selecting table column from bottom to top:**
[image]
[image]

Comment: About your bottom image, in this case, when 3 cells are selected, do you want to add a bookmark to only one cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

```
function myFunction() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument(); 
  var selection = doc.getSelection().getRangeElements();
  var pos = selection[0].getElement();
  doc.addBookmark(doc.newPosition(pos,0));
}
```

Screenshots:

Full table
[image]

Column only
[image]

Single table cell
[image]